# Macvim crashing about hourly

Tags: macvim, vi

Any hints on stabilizing MacVim?  I have version "Custom Version 7.4 (73)" as shown in screenshot

[image]

Typically MacVim is crashing when I am working on a *different* application - not when actually editing within vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an active github project that has fixed some bugs related to Yosemite.  Here is the repo:

https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim